# SharePoint Custom Form - Display CheckInComment History

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, custom-controls, versioning

How does one go about displaying the CheckInComment history for a document library item in a custom edit/display form?

I know that the document history is stored as a collection and I tried using a LINQ statement like the one below in order to try and retrieve the history of comments but I didn't get back any results.

```
var file = SPContext.Current.ListItem.File;
var versions = file.Versions.OfType<SPFileVersion>().Select(v => v.CheckInComment).ToArray();
var comments = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, versions);
```

The plan was to then go and set the text value of a label field equal to the value stored in the "comments" variable.

No such luck.

In addition, I am also trying to use the Comments field in my Edit Form and have tried various different approaches but can't seem to figure out which actual field stores the comments.

```
<SharePoint:AppendOnlyHistory runat="server" FieldName="V3Comments" ControlMode="Edit" />
```

No dice.

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" ID="ApproverComments" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="Approver Comments" />
```

Nope. Nothing. Nada.

All I want to do is have a scrollable div on my View form that shows the CheckInComments history and also show the same thing on my Edit form but also have a SPMultiLineText field that will allow users to enter a new CheckInComment -but without actually performing a "Check In". Meaning, I want the users to be able to edit the metadata of the document library List Item and then use the CheckInComments field to keep a history of the changes so when they look at the Version History of the List Item then they can not only see what metadata properties changed from version to version but also see the comments.